# Node curried function with lazy value assigned to it

Tags: javascript, node.js, functional-programming, currying

I have a function like...

```
const constant = v => () => v;
```

And I have a value like...

```
let someGlobalValue;
```

And then I have another `const` like...

```
const curriedFunction = constant(someGlobalValue);
```

Now... when I do this...

```
someGlobalValue = 123;
consoleLog(curriedFunction());
```

The output is `undefined`.

I know why this is. It's because I have already created the instance of the curried function with the stored value when the file is loaded and it is set at that point. So changing `someGlobalValue` isn't being read at the time of calling the curried function.

But... is there a way to not do this?

I need to be able to set the `someGlobalValue` before calling the curried function and for it to return the value I just set. But I can't work out how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: You can just reference the outer scoped variable (`someGlobalValue`, don't use it as an argument), but that's impure. I don't think what you're looking for is possible functionally, depends on what you're willing to sacrifice

Comment: @CertainPerformance sorry, typo. :D fixed the typo. I was using letin my code.

Comment: I'm wondering why not just `const getGlobalValue = () => someGlobalValue`, or something of the sort

Comment: Don't use global variables. Some people even claim using global constants is bad style when your application grows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to be able to set the `someGlobalValue` before calling the curried function and for it to return the value I just set. But I can't work out how to do this.

Sorry, but this is the antithesis of functional discipline. In functional style, functions offer referential transparency, where a function always produces the same result when given the same arguments. The function you describe is impure as it can produce a different result, depending on the state of `someGlobalValue`.

Another hint lies in the name of the `constant` function. When we use a *constant*, the programmer relies on the fact that the value will *not* change.

Finally, your `curriedFunction` variable is named poorly. It's not a curried function so this name only serves to confuse you.

```js
let someGlobalValue = 1

const impureFunction = () => someGlobalValue

console.log(impureFunction())
// 1

someGlobalValue = 2

console.log(impureFunction())
// 2
```

Your question is zoomed in very closely on a tiny granule of code. If you can share more context and show us how you intend to use these granules, we may be able to offer more effective advice.

Comment: I actually changed this up again to pass the value I wanted into a larger function that then contained the `constant` function that I was using before. I agree that it wasn't a functional way of doing things. This step lead me to find a better way of doing it but it definitely helped me get there. Thanks :D

Comment: In the end I did it like... `const outerFunction = input => () => { ... constant(input) }` this meant I could then delete the global value I had and just insert it into the function. Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

You could hand over an object reference and set the value in the object later. But this is not advisable, because it confuses the reader.

```js
const constant = o => () => o.value;
const someGlobalValue = {};
const curriedFunction = constant(someGlobalValue);

someGlobalValue.value = 123;

console.log(curriedFunction());
```

Comment: This requires external mutation, though (impure, not functional)

Comment: is *pure* required?

Comment: @NinaScholz I can't change the definition of `constant` as it is used elsewhere.

Comment: @NinaScholz however, this has given me an idea to explore. Will have another look at the problem thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

> I have a function like...
>
> ```
> const constant = v => () => v;
> ```

good utility if you want to always return a constant value. But that's not what you want here.

The simplest solution:

```
const curriedFunction = () => someGlobalValue;
```

then `curriedFunction()` will always return the value of `someGlobalValue` even if you change it.

Comment: Boom! This works. Thanks :D So simple but I was blinded by the `constant` function that I had :D

Comment: Nitpick, `curriedFunction` isn't a curried function. Don't duplicate the OP's mistake in your answer.

Comment: @user633183 I'm aware, especially in my version. I just kept the name so that it is clear where I'm stepping in in OP's code.

Answer (score 1):

If it's really a global (or at least in-scope) variable, and you need the then-current version of it when calling `curriedFunction`, you don't want to curry the function at all. But you've said you can't change `constant`, so you don't get a lot of choice and have to curry it Just In Time, e.g.:

```
const curriedFunction = () => constant(someGlobalValue)();
```

That creates and throws away a function every time you call it, but if you can't change `constant`, you don't have a lot of choice. Fortunately, JavaScript engines are *really* fast at doing that.

Live Copy:

```js
const constant = v => () => v;

let someGlobalValue;

const curriedFunction = () => constant(someGlobalValue)();

someGlobalValue = 123;
console.log(curriedFunction());
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. This works for now. The `globalValue` I was referring to is only at file scope. I don't like the fact that I have to edit it this way. But I can use this for now. I may actually try seeing if I can stop the mutation of it at all. Thanks for this for now though :D